# How to send a variable to the middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, express-router

I have an express-router route as follows:

```
.post(
    authController.protect,
    itemController.createItem, //create Item
    itemController.sendNotification('new-item'), //if user exists send notification

  );
```

the createItem controller has some logic that can run sendNotifications with type('new-match') and if skipped will continue to the next controller using `next()` as follows:

```
if(foo) next()
else sendNotifications('new-match')
```

my sendNotifications middleware is defined as follows:

```
const sendNotification = type =>
  catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.userFound) {
      await Notification.create({ user: req.userFound, notType: type });
      const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.userFound, {
        $inc: { notifications: 1 }
      });
      req.userFoundEmail = user.email;
    }
    next();
  });
exports.sendNotification = sendNotification;
```

My problem is that when sendNotifications middleware is induced from the route stack it will have access to `req,res,next` but when it is called from the controller itself `req,res,next` are `undefined`

I am calling the sendNotification from inside the controller as explained above:

```
sendNotification('new-match');
```

How i can provide access to req,res,next from both ways?

Comment: What is `catchAsync`? Your middleware is being passed to it as an argument

Comment: it is just a try catch handler method. so without that my function would be
`const sendNotification = type =>
 async (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.userFound) {
      await Notification.create({ user: req.userFound, notType: type });
      const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.userFound, {
        $inc: { notifications: 1 }
      });
      req.userFoundEmail = user.email;
    }
    next();
  };
exports.sendNotification = sendNotification;`